# react-key-index sample example does not work

Tags: reactjs, npm, hashids, react-key-index

I would like to use react-key-index extension in order to generate unique id's.
I was trying to implement their sample example, but no matter what I do, it still throws me the same error:

> TypeError: Hashids is not a constructor

link: [react-key-index npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-key-index)

Here is that pretty simple example:

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import keyIndex from "react-key-index";
import './App.css';

function App() {
  let arr = ["one", "two", "three"];
  arr = keyIndex(arr, 1);

  const list = arr.map(arr => <li key={arr.id}>{arr.value}</li>);
  return <ul>{list}</ul>;
}

export default App;
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

[image]

Please, do you have any idea where do I do a mistake? I am trying to set it going in completely new react project (create-react-app). From my point of view i have implemented it correctly (but obviously i have not).
And here is how that error looks like in the browser:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you run `npm install` or perhaps `npm install --save hashids`? `hashids` is a dependency of that npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-key-index

The `require('hashids');` should load up that NPM package if you have it installed; if it doesn't find it, I would expect an error like this.

Comment: The error is in a Library File, not OP's code, I guess.

Comment: I have not install hashids explicitly but node_modules folder contains it so i guess this is not that problem. And require('hashids') returns it too.

Comment: @RadekAdler  At that point in the code, is `HashIds` in fact a constructor, if you put a breakpoint there?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using an older version of [**`react-key-index`**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-key-index)

Try using **`V0.1.1`** and check if that works for you.

I tried it with React **`16.8.6`** and it seems to be working well for me.

> Here's a [**Working Sample CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-key-index-demo-2d6zm) for your ref.

Comment: Hi, I have rearranged my question exactly according to your answer. I have posted my package.json including identical versions as your project. It still does not work. Im my opinion, the problem must consist of i am loading app.js in index.js (2 files) but you have only used one file (and sample code in npmjs does the same too). Everything else is a carbon copy of your project. But it sounds me crazy if such a detail causes such a troubles.

Comment: @SiddAjmera the example in codesandbox does not work.

Comment: @Cubancoffee, not sure what happened! It was working the last time I saw it.